# Turtlebot gmapping demo very long on hydro

Tags: navigation, turtlebot, ros-hydro, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'am trying to use the turtlebot on hydro (all packets up to date).
Gmapping need a huge time to update the map, is it a normal behavior ?

This a sceencast example of rviz based on the demo :
youtu.be/z-ZeBIad1YI

Thanks for your help !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172882/turtlebot-gmapping-demo-very-long-on-hydro/) by [Jérôme](https://answers.ros.org/users/5102/j%C3%A9r%C3%B4me/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2014-06-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-06-27**:
Mapping needs much computation power but gmapping is not slow as your video shows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you checked your setting for the map_update_interval parameter? Probably set in `gmapping.launch.xml`.

http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping?distro=hydro

---

Originally posted by [zsaigol](https://answers.ros.org/users/6094/zsaigol/) with karma: 225 on 2014-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0